# Property 'server' is private and only accessible within class 'Socket<ListenEvents, EmitEvents, ServerSideEvents>

Tags: socket.io, nestjs

I am getting this error with getway.ts file. I am trying to use Nestjs/websockets, and Socket.io to connect my Ionic App.

[image: getway.ts code]